# Html cannot grab or input data from xml file

Tags: php, html, xml

I am currently experiencing an issue here. I have my html login page, once I click login, it will jump to php and run the php and grab data from xml. However, when I click login. It will just jump to php without taking any actions.

Does anyone know what the code is lacking?

Html page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body>

    <fieldset>
      <form method="post" action="login.php">
            <p>Email* : <input type="email" name="email" id="email"/></p>
            <p>Password* : <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/> 
   </p> 
        <div class="buttoninput">
                <input type="submit" name="login "value="Login" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" />    
        </div>
      </form>
    </fieldset>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $customerxml = simplexml_load_file('customer.xml');

    $email_add = "";
    $passw = "";
    $customerID = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($customerxml); $i++){

        $email_add = $customerxml->info[$i]->Email;
        $passw = $customerxml->info[$i]->Password;
        $customerID = $customerxml->info[$i]->CustomerID;

        if(($email != $email_add) || ($passw != $pass)){
            $message = "wrong email/password";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }


        if(($email == $email_add) && ($passw == $pass)){

            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

            unset($mydata->info[$i]->Password);


            $_SESSION['customer-info'] = json_encode($customerxml->info[$i]);


            exit(header("Location: ./bidding.php"));
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="submit" name="login "value="Login" />
```

there is space in `name="login "` remove that space.because of the space `if(isset($_POST['login'])) {` this is getting failed

Comment: Thank you all of your kindly reply. Can't imagine I can have this such simple mistake. My issue has been solved now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
```

by

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
```

in login.php file or remove space in

```
<input type="submit" name="login "value="Login" />
```

(`name="login "`)